# Drop all stashes associated with a particular branch

Tags: git

I'm in the habit of stashing my changes in git and applying them again with `git stash apply`. This has the advantage of keeping me from accidentally losing a stash I made, but it also means that my list of stashes grows rather quickly.

When I'm done with a branch, I go back through my stash list and manually remove all of the stashes associated with the branch. Is there a way to do this in a single command?

For example, my current stash list looks like this:

```
kevin@localhost:~/my/dev/work$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 346f844 Commit comment
stash@{1}: WIP on second_issues: a2f63e5 Commit comment
stash@{2}: WIP on second_issues: c1c96a9 Commit comment
stash@{3}: WIP on second_issues: d3c7949 Commit comment
stash@{4}: WIP on second_issues: d3c7949 Commit comment
stash@{5}: WIP on second_issues: d3c7949 Commit comment
stash@{6}: WIP on second_issues: 9964898 Commit comment
```

Is there a command that would drop all of the stashes from `second_issues`?

Comment: +1 very interesting question. Will the stashes always be sequential in `git stash list`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. When I get busy with a lot of tasks, I'll start switching branches a lot and end up with intermixed stashes.

Comment: I thought that might be the case and wanted to clarify since the stashes in the example are sequential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this? It's a quick and dirty way that drops the stashes created on a given branch.

It simply lists all stashes, searches with grep for the stashes created on a branch, gets its stash name and finally passes those names `git stash drop` through xargs.

```
git stash list | grep -E 'stash@{[0-9]+}.+ YOUR_BRANCH_NAME' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | xargs git stash drop
```

---

Edit

Digging in the man pages, it says the `git stash list` also accepts `git log` format options.
So we tell it to print lines that only match `YOUR_BRANCHNAME`, and of those lines to just print its "reflag identity name" (`%gd: shortened reflag selector, e.g., stash@{1}`, from the man page).
Then, we pass the output to `xargs` to drop the stash.

```
git stash list --grep='YOUR_BRANCHNAME' --format='%gd' | xargs git stash drop
```

Comment: I am getting too many revision specified error when there are more than 1 stash in a branch

Answer (score 3):

The stash is not dependent on any branch. The stash is just the stash for your repository. Each repository has exactly one stash, but you can put as many change sets as you want in a stash and it will keep them for later. As such it is not the case that your stashes are different between branches. In your case stash@{6} will show you the same commit no matter what branch you have checked out. If you want to clear your stash you can run `git stash clear` and that will clear your stash of all stashed changes for that repo. This is a pretty destructive operation so be careful when using it.

Comment: This may be true. However, the commit message for a stash includes the branch where the commit was made. I believe that this is what the OP is referring to.

Comment: MonadNewb is right. I understand that stashes are visible from any branch and can be applied anywhere. I want to delete stashes based on which branch I created them from. Thanks, though!

Comment: Okay, that is a much more complex operation, you would need to write a BASH script that would do that for you by either viewing the results of `git stash list` or by actually transversing the .git folder for where the information on what has been stashed from where is stored. I'm not sure where that info is, but based viewing `git stash help` what you are asking for does not seem possible without a BASH script of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to check the relationship between a stash and a given branch is to check if the parent commit of the stash is contained in your branch.

The parent commit of a stash is the commit from which the stash was created.  If this commit is present in your branch of interest you could drop them or take the necessary action.

There is a small bash script to detect if any of your stashes originated from a commit that is currently contained in `HEAD`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all stashes, like "stash@{0}", "stash@{1}", and so on
stashList=$(git stash list | grep -o "^stash@{[0-9]*}")

for stashRef in $stashList; do

    # Obtain hashes for the stash and its first parent
    currentHash=$(git rev-parse $stashRef)
    parentHash=$(git rev-parse $stashRef^)

    echo "$stashRef: $currentHash"
    echo "parent: $parentHash"

    # merge-base checks for the common parent
    mergeBase=$(git merge-base $parentHash HEAD)

    # If a commit is contained in another commit, it will be the base
    # commit returned by merge-base
    if [[ $mergeBase == $parentHash ]]; then
        echo 'Contained in HEAD'
    else
        echo 'Not contained in HEAD'
    fi
done
```